# Android SQLite querying max/min values

Tags: android, sqlite

In my android application I'm using a sqlite database with a table called "event_table" that looks like this:
[image]

My goal is to find the best time or distance for each athlete_id for each event they participate in.

My querying code looks like this:

```
TrackAndFieldDBHelper mOpenHelper = new TrackAndFieldDBHelper(this);
SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();

boolean isTimedEvent = Event.isEventTimed(this, event);

String rawQuery = "SELECT * FROM event_table INNER JOIN (SELECT athlete_id " + (isTimedEvent ? ", MIN(" : ", MAX(") + "sort_result) AS MinOrMaxResult FROM event_table GROUP BY athlete_id) joinedTable ON event_table.athlete_id = joinedTable.athlete_id AND event_table.sort_result = joinedTable.MinOrMaxResult";

Cursor data = db.rawQuery(rawQuery, null);
    if (data != null) {
        if (data.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                long athleteID = data.getLong(data.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TrackAndFieldContract.EventEntry.COLUMN_ATHLETE_ID));
                String event = data.getString(data.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TrackAndFieldContract.EventEntry.COLUMN_EVENT));
                String result = data.getString(data.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TrackAndFieldContract.EventEntry.COLUMN_RESULT));
                Log.d(TAG, "athlete id: " + athleteID + " event: " + event + " result: " + result);
            } while (data.moveToNext());
        }
        data.close();
    }
    db.close(); 
}
```

The results of the log look like this:

athlete id: 4 event: 3000m result: 12:08.24

athlete id: 5 event: 3000m result: 13:47.68

athlete id: 1 event: Discus result: 130-00

athlete id: 2 event: Discus result: 114-00

athlete id: 3 event: 400m result: 61.00

athlete id: 6 event: 400m result: 61.50

For those 3 events (3000m, Discus, 400m) and athlete_id's the result values are correct.  I do get the correct max or min.  So my question is what happened to the other events?  (100m, 100H, 1500m, Shot Put)  Shouldn't my query include those events as well?  I haven't been able to figure out why.  I've tried to add a WHERE clause for the missing events and I get nothing.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you tried using `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: The GROUP BY clause is in query.

Comment: I mean by adding `event` as part of it

Comment: That actually might work.  It seems to be working for events that I need a max for, but events where I'm searching for the min, I'm getting an error "wrong number of arguments to function MIN()"

Comment: I see the problem.  Jimit your answer works.  Thanks!

Comment: great! have a good day

Comment: Hey! Enlighten the other readers too, by creating an answer. "I see the problem.... Silence" is not nice. ;-) And you could maybe make a smaller MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your question? And not as a screenshot?